# count number of times a loop runs

Tags: logic, complexity-theory

I am new to programming I want to know how many times iteration takes place in the following function.I just want to how the number of iteration depends on a and b
where A and B are binary numbers .For example A=101010 and b=1011010.
The following is algorithm for adding two numbers without using + operator

```
  while B is greater than 0:
        U = A XOR B
        V = A AND B
        A = U
        B = V * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the usual convention that values that are non-zero are considered `True` and that `0` evaluates to `False`.

Since you didn't specify the initial value of `A`, let's consider both cases (I'm assuming that `B==True` at init otherwise there would be no iterations):

```
CASE 1: A==False => (U==True and V==False) => B=0 => iterations stop 

CASE 2:A==True => (U==False and V==True) => B=True, A=False => this is now CASE 1
```

So, depending on the initial value of `A` and asuming `B==True` at the start, there will be either `1` or `2` iterations.